# Remove $ sign from stock charts

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

Has anyone been able to remove the $ sign from a Kendo Stockchart?
I am trying to use this chart as it has the navigation box but I am not using it for financial information, but rather quantity over time.

I've tried changing the template for the value axis, but without success.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this using the [format](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-valueAxis.labels.format) option:

```
valueAxis: [{
    labels: {
        format: "{0}"
    }
}
```